# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools_scm<3,>=4.1.2

Tags: python, django, pip, djangular

I'm trying to install `djangular-serve` in my project but I'm unsure what version of setuptools_Scm it's asking for.

```
  Using cached djangular-serve-2.1.0.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=49.6.0
        Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools_scm<3,>=4.1.2 (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0, 1.15.1rc1, 1.15.4, 1.15.5, 1.15.6, 1.15.7, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.17.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.5.0, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.1.0.dev0, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.3.2, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.0.4, 7.0.5)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools_scm<3,>=4.1.2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I'm confused, how can the version be greater than 4.1.2 but less than 3? Do I need to fix the setup? How do I download the package and do that if I need to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `djangular-serve` in [`pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/forafekt/djangular-serve/blob/356797dd6fe78db5da815f0d3ad3601c6ddf739c/pyproject.toml#L41). Please [report the bug](https://github.com/forafekt/djangular-serve/issues). The fact that nobody reported the bug in two years suggests the package is not very popular among users.